# C++ File Parser/stdin input - Will This Algorithm Work?

Tags: c++, opengl, stdin, fileparsing

I'm trying to implement a line scan conversion in OpenGL from stdin that lists line end points like so:

```
L 0, 0, 150, 150
L -20, 40, 22, 55
[...]
Z
```

Where the [...] is just more of the same, and the Z character is a convenient termination operator, though end of file may also work.

Given that I want to output these lines in OpenGL, is it best to first store them to an array, or read in and display all in one go? My thought is to try something like this (kinda psuedocoded):

```
bool loadData(int[] lines, string fileName) {

ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open("fileName.txt");

if (!inputFile.is_open()) {
    return false;
}

if (inputFile.is_open()) {
    while (getline(fileName, i, ',')) {
        //Write to lines array
    }

}
inputFile.close();
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to extend support for Z termination, or how to accept console/stdin input as well. Can my algorithm be extended handle both files and console simply, or am I better off dividing up the approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way OpenGL applications work, you normally have to be able to redraw whenever you are asked to redraw. For example, you have to be able to redraw when the window size changes. You may be asked to redraw after your window was covered by another window, and then uncovered.

Loading the geometry for a file every time you need to redraw would be very inefficient. I would definitely suggest reading the file once, and storing the content in a data structure. Since you're using C++, you could have a little `Line` object that stores the description of a line, and then use a `std::vector<Line>` to store your list of lines.

As for the parsing, it seems simplest to me to read full lines in the main input loop, which means getting rid of the `','` separator. Then decide what kind of line you're dealing with by testing the first character. If it's a `Z`, break out of the input loop. If it's a `L`, you can pick apart the line using an `std::istringstream`.

You can easily use the same code for file input and standard input. `std::cin` is just another stream, very much like the `std::ifstream` you get from opening a file. For example, the overall layout could look like this (naming for illustration):

```
void yourFileInputMethod(std::istream& inputStrm) {
    // parse content of inputStrm
}

if (youWantToReadFromAFile) {
    std::ifstream inputFile(filename);
    yourFileInputMethod(inputFile);
} else {
    yourFileInputMethod(std::cin);
}
```

If you don't want an extra method, you can do the same thing with a reference variable for the stream:

```
std::ifstream inputFile;
if (youWantToReadFromAFile) {
    inputFile.open(filename);
}

std::istream& inputStrm = inputFile.is_open() ? inputFile : std::cin;

// parse content of inputStrm
```